# Scrapying a table with <p style="position

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to scrape a page where I have several paragraph tags :

```
 <p style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:65px">
```

and I have 4 elements in each line as the following :

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:65px"><span style="virtical-align:top;font-size:9px;font-family:GothicText;color:#000000;letter-spacing:0.00000px;stringWidth:86px;">INFORMATION A_110</span></p> 
<p style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:173px"><span style="virtical-align:top;font-size:9px;font-family:GothicText;color:#000000;letter-spacing:1.64571px;stringWidth:115px;">INFORMATION B_110</span></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:403px"><span style="virtical-align:top;font-size:9px;font-family:GothicText;color:#000000;letter-spacing:1.55520px;stringWidth:194px;">INFORMATION C_110</span></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:814px"><span style="virtical-align:top;font-size:9px;font-family:GothicText;color:#000000;letter-spacing:1.59158px;stringWidth:151px;"> INFORMATION D_110</span></p> 
<p style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:1080px"><span style="virtical-align:top;font-size:9px;font-family:GothicText;color:#000000;letter-spacing:0.00000px;stringWidth:36px;"> INFORMATION E_110</span></p>
```

I would like to stack `INFORMATION A_110, B_110, C_110, D_110` into a table for each line.

What I do so far: I record for some pages the exact position (`left :1080px`, etc.) and I do an xparse for each position to extract the information. The problem is that I don't detect automatically the position (`top:110px;left:1080px` for instance), I need to enter it manually.

The drawback of this approach is that I can omit some data points (for instance if now the position becomes `top:111px;left:1080px` instead of `top:110px;left:1080px`).

Comment: Did you try XPath `//p[starts-with(., "INFORMATION ")]`?

Comment: I created https://jsfiddle.net/ose6r18j/ as a reference. Can you please clarify why is the position of the elements on the screen important for your problem? It is not clear to me, what is the expected that you are expecting in different scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Information can be anything: a name, a description, a date, an ID, etc. I clarify why the position of the elements on the screen is important for my problem on jsfiddle.net/ose6r18j. Basically I have several lines and what you see here is only one line. All the columns can correspond to a variable (like a date for instance, or a description). I want to assign an information to a variable (whether it is a description, a time, etc.). Basically it is making a (transparent) table, but without the good tag (because the HTML code comes from the translation of a PDF).